# AWS Blue/Green deployment on EC2 failing on one of the instance during ApplicationStop - unknown error, appspec.yml file doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, blue-green-deployment

Basically we are running blue/green deployment for our EC2. We deploy our application on multiple EC2 instances and I found that one of the replacement instance is failing during ApplicationStop with "Unknown Error". I checked AWS codedeploy log and the new replacement instances and they both look identical, except that the problematic instance is missing the appspec.yml for some reason.

I am trying to find out what are the possible reasons to have this weird situation? How could appspec.yml file be gone? The instance has access to the internet and I can confirm that, IAM access for both instances should also be identical, codedeploy agent is also installed and running.

Both replacement instances should be successfully deployed (as it is used to be)

[image]

AWS codedeploy agent log:

```
2023-09-12T05:33:06 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38423)]: master 38423: Spawned child 1/1
2023-09-12T05:33:07 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2023-09-12T05:33:07 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
2023-09-12T05:33:07 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Archives to retain is: 5}
2023-09-12T05:33:07 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
2023-09-12T05:33:07 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
2023-09-12T05:33:07 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.6.0-49_deb.
2023-09-12T05:33:07 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38423)]: Started master 38423 with 1 children
2023-09-12T05:33:52 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.198042 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:527496958080:instance/i-05e67511719e2359a")  

2023-09-12T05:33:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.6.0-49_deb.
2023-09-12T05:34:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.255058 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:527496958080:instance/i-05e67511719e2359a")  

2023-09-12T05:34:40 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.6.0-49_deb.
2023-09-12T05:35:25 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.36634 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:527496958080:instance/i-05e67511719e2359a")  

2023-09-12T05:35:26 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.6.0-49_deb.
2023-09-12T05:36:11 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.175998 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:527496958080:instance/i-05e67511719e2359a")  

2023-09-12T05:36:12 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.6.0-49_deb.
2023-09-12T05:36:57 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(38425)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.326833 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:527496958080:instance/i-05e67511719e2359a")
```

EDIT 1:
On the successfully deployed instance, I can find the downloaded code artifact on the instance. But I can't find the same deployment archive on the failed instance.
[image: code artifact on the successfully deployed instance]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)